# (Python) Why can a function memorize this?

Tags: python, memory-management, user-defined-functions

I ran the following small code

```
def func2(xxx=[]):
        xxx.append(1)
        print xxx
        return None
func2()
func2()
func2()
```

The output is the following:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
```

Which variable does the program save those lists [1], [1,1],[1,1,1] in? 
Why doesn't the computer clear the memory allocated to the function after the function is executed?

I also tried the following function

```
def func(x=2):
        print 'at the beginning of the function x = ', x
        x=x+1
        print 'after the value is changed x = ', x
        return x
func()
func()
func()
```

The output is the following:

```
at the beginning of the function x =  2
after the value is changed x =  3
at the beginning of the function x =  2
after the value is changed x =  3
at the beginning of the function x =  2
after the value is changed x =  3
```

And it turns out that this function performs normally. What's the major difference between func and func2?

Comment: To put is simply, a new list is not created each time `func2()` is called. `xxx` is the same list each time `func2()` is called. Python only creates the `xxx` list _**once_** during import time, and `xxx` is the same list used throughout the program.

Comment: @ChristianDean I tried a similar function where the default argument is a number. And there is no such behavior. I have added the detail to the original question.

Comment: That is because a list is mutable - that is, it can be modified after creation - while and integer object is immutable.

Comment: @ChristianDean what's the motivation of making list a mutable object?

Comment: The motivation is that programmers needed and still do need an object with container-like properties from which you can easily add, remove, and keep track of many data.